# Mutual TLS on NGINX with 2 CAs?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm curious, if I have a cert and private key issued by a well-known CA such as letsencrypt to establish a secure connection, but I'm using mutual TLS on NGINX, is it possible to have only the mutual tls auth reference a custom CA?

For example:

Connection is established and verified from Let's Encrypt CA. When client visits a path that requires a client cert to be present, I want that certificate to validate against my own custom CA I made via OpenSSL. Is that flow possible by just adding the CA to be my custom CA?

Comment: Yes, nginx verifies the client cert (if requested and obtained) against one or more CA certs in either `ssl_client_certificate` or `ssl_trusted_certificate` which is/are independent of and can be different from the (one) CA used for the server's own cert. [See the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html)

Comment: Thanks Dave for the info